# How do I use iTunes' "Download Later" feature?

Tags: itunes, itunes-store

I redeemed a movie in iTunes on my Mac and choose download later. Later, I choose `Store > Check for Available Downloads…` and it reported that all of my stuff has already been downloaded. So where do I go to get my movie onto my Mac?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the problem here is that I have actually been looking for something in the iTunes application UI to do this. Rather, the solution seems to be in the web pages served by the iTunes Store.

1. Go to the iTunes Store.
2. Scroll to the bottom of the page.
3. Under "Features", choose "[Purchased](https://se.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStoreElements.woa/wa/purchases?cc=us)"[image: Click on purchase]
4. Choose the media type you want (it may help to choose "Not on this computer").[image: Choose media type]
5. Click the iCloud icon to (re-)download it.[image: Click here to download.]